# performance php search file vs key - value path

Tags: php, performance, file, search

Is it faster search file in a tree of directory or search a file path in a single associate key - value file for load a class?
example first case:

```
dir
   file1
   file2
   dir2
       file3
       dir3
           file4
   dircommon
       file5
```

example second case:
single file ( test.config.txt ) with associate key - value:

```
file1=/dir/
file2=/dir/
file3=/dir/dir2/
file4=/dir/dir2/dir3
```

I search file4 and then load class defined into file4

What is more faster method?

There is a faster and perfomance method to manage depencencies of php files?

Answer (score 0):

The first method is easier because you don't have to update your index file for every new model/controller you add, and I don't think the performance difference is going to be that big unless you're loading thousands of classes on every page load, in which case you should just switch to Java. :P

Our in-house framework just searches file paths based on the class name... i.e. Application_Model_Person would map to '<include dir>/Application/Model/Person.php'.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is fairly simple.

Start looking for the solution no sooner than you have problem.

Looks like you have no problem right now, save for imaginary one.
So, I'd go for the more usable solution which is apparently not one requires additional file to mirror filesystem structure.